# v-select being triggered automatically if incorrect

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

The v-select that I change the option is triggering the other v-select automatically, the operation is to be independent between them, the issue that I am unable to get this code right. Someone with more experience than I could help me with?

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="res"
      item-key="Name"
      class="elevation-23"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.path="{ item }">
        <v-select
          v-model="cSel"
          :items="item.path"
      ></v-select>
      </template>    
    </v-data-table>

data () {
    return {
      expanded: [],
      singleExpand: false,
      cSel: 'A',
      res: [
        {
          fullName: 'name 1',
          med: 'med 1',
          startDate: 'start  date 1',
          path:  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        },
         {
          fullName: 'name 2',
          med: 'med 2',
          startDate: 'start  date 2',
          path:  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        },
       ],
       totalRes: 0,
        search: '',
        loading: false,
        options: {
          page: 1,
          itemsPerPage: 40,
        },
        headers: [
      { text: 'Name', value: 'fullName' },
      { text: 'Med', value: 'med' },
      { text: 'Start Date', value: 'startDate' },
      { text: 'Create  ', value: 'path', width: '200' },
     ],      
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using only one `cSel` variable for all items. That's why one change affects every select component.

You could either include the variable in every item. So you'd have `item.cSel`.

Or you convert `cSel` to an object and access it with an identifier:

```js
cSel: {}
```

```html
<v-select
  v-model="cSel[item.fullName]"
  :items="item.path"
></v-select>
```

I used the `fullName` property in this case. As long as that's unique this solution should work but it would probably be better to have an `id` property.